# Mosh doesn't reconnect

Tags: ssh, mosh

I installed [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) on a desktop and server yesterday (compiled latest v1.2.3 from source) and it works fine. I left the session open yesterday and have come into the office today to find my mosh session is dead, with the error along the top of the terminal window:

```
mosh: Last contact 14723 seconds ago. [To quit: Ctrl-^ .]
```

I thought mosh should auto reconnect, or do I have to manually tell it to reconnect? If so, how? Or, is it a setting I need to enabled somewhere, to auto reconnect?

I left an SSH session open to the same server, this is still working just fine.

Comment: mosh automatically reconnects but if you have screen or tmux running and detached/reattached the screen-session from somewhere else mosh can't reconnect

Comment: Well mine hasn't reconnected, but my seperate SSH window is still active (perhaps just a momentary drop in the night as this is over ADSL). In the SSH window I am just sitting at the terminal prompt, in the mosh window, I had a screen session open in which I was running irssi. Do you think its something to do with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mosh will reconnect by default, no additional configuration should be done for that.

As for your case, I suspect one of the following:

1. mosh daemon has died on the server side for some reason. Check if it's still running.
2. Somehow the UDP port mosh uses has been blocked. It might be a problem in the router between the client and the server, or a problem in the network configuration on either side.

Comment: Being the massive Baboon that I am (probably an insult to Baboons) I had missed some server maintenance that went on, and my iptables rules for mosh was removed. Network problems, cheers!

Comment: Unnecessary self-deprecation!